# 'invalid continuation byte'- csv with multiple encodings?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to download and parse a [U.S. Census csv](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/metro/totals/csa-est2019-alldata.csv) file in python. I'm getting a recurring error that suggests that there are multiple encodings in the file.

I got the file encoding using

```
import urllib.request 
import io
url = 'https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/metro/totals/csa-est2019-alldata.csv'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'data/source_files/census/city/2010.csv')
```

This gives me the file encoding

```
io.open('data/source_files/census/city/2010.csv')

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='data/source_files/census/city/2010.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

But the encoding doesn't seem to be correct? I tried using chardet.

```
with open('data/source_files/census/city/2010.csv', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
    print(chardet.detect(f.read()))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 11902: invalid continuation byte
```

I get a smilar error no matter what I try

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/source_files/census/city/' + '2010.csv')
```

```
import csv
with open("data/source_files/census/city/2010.csv","r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['CBSA'])
```

All these approaches are giving me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 11902: invalid continuation byte
```

Any advice on how to get around this?

Comment: It seems to be encoded in ISO 8859-15. As a side note, when using chardet, you have to provide bytes, so don't try opening it as text - you don't even know the correct encoding to use, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Latin-1` is a single byte encoding family so everything in it should be defined in `UTF-8`. But sometime Latin-1 wins.

Use this, If it shows the error of UTF-8.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/metro/totals/csa-est2019-alldata.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(url , encoding='latin-1')
data.head()
```

It should show you below data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first code doesn't get the encoding, it just downloads the file.

The second code opens the file with an OS-specific default encoding, specifically the value of `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.  UTF-8 was the default for the OS used and it wasn't correct for the file.

The third code opens the file as `UTF-8` again, and that is the cause of failure, not `chardet`.

Use the `requests` library instead:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.get('https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/metro/totals/csa-est2019-alldata.csv')
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
```

The correct encoding is `ISO-8859-1` also known as `latin1`.  `r.text` will be the correctly decoded text.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that CSV file is not UTF-8 Encoded, so you have to use the correct option to help the File wrapper decode it correctly.

In this case, the CSV is encoded in ANSI instead of UTF-8:

```
open("...", encoding="ANSI")
```

Comment: on my system I get unknown encoding : ANSI. How to fix that?

Comment: @RishabhKumar `ANSI` is an alias for `mbcs`, and is only available in Windows.  It's a shortcut to say use whatever Windows considers the native OS encoding.